# Firebase: Access to different sections depending on user

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is my approach on how to allow specific users to access their allocated 'shop' object.

```
func shopFetch() {

        self.shop.removeAll()
        let shopRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("shop").child(someIDforShop).child("menu")
        shopRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                let something1 = dictionary["some1"]
                let something2 = dictionary["some2"]

                let shopper = Shop(some1: something1, some2: something2)
                self.shop.insert(shopper, at: 0)

                self.collection.reloadData()
            }

            }, withCancel: nil)

    }
```

These are my security rules

```
rules: {
  "users": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth != null || auth.uid == $uid",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        "$yourShop": {
          ".read": "true"
    }
  },

  "shop": {
    "$yourShop": {
      ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child($yourShop).val() == true",
      ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child($yourShopManager).val() == true || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() == true"
      }
   },
}
```

Let's say I have this in my Database:

```
<app-name>: {
    "shop": {
      "shop1": {
        "menu": {
          "some1": "thing1",
          "some2": "thing2"
        }
      },
      "shop2": {
        "menu": {
          "some1": "thing1",
          "some2": "thing2"
        }
      },
      "shop3": {
        "menu": {
          "some1": "thing1",
          "some2": "thing2"
        }
      },
      "users": {
       "K4of4ofp32kfoE": {
         "shop": {
           "shop1": true
         }
      },
      "fj3i53ogF34oGf329ieQ": {
         "shop": {
           "shop2": true
         }
      },

}
```

What should I write in `let shopRef` in `someIDforShop`?
Doing this, will allow each user to access his/her 'shop'. I tried with `childByAutoID()`, assuming it will fetch the data relative to the user, as specified in the rules. But `shopFetch()` returns nothing when I ask to `print(snapshot)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to get the variable name of each shop for each user.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

let shopVar = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userReference = DataService.instance.REF_USERS.child((user?.uid)!).child("shop")
        userReference.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in       

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

                let shopName = dict["name"] as! String
                print(shopName)

                self.shopVar = shopName

            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Rules change

```
"users": {
       "K4of4ofp32kfoE": {
         "shop": {
           "name": "coolShop"
         }
      },
      "fj3i53ogF34oGf329ieQ": {
         "shop": {
           "name": "fancyShop"
         }
      },
}
```

Then I replace `shopVar` -> `someIDforShop` in `shopFetch()`

Now every user receives his/her own personal 'shop' items.